# How to copy files to Amazon EC2 Windows instance from my local machine?

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2

I have created a new Windows instance on Amazon EC2. I want to copy some files from my local machine to the instance. How do I go about it?

Answer (score 36):

Actually we can take benefit from the disk sharing feature of mstsc. Here is how it works:

1. Go to find the RDP file amazon asked you to downloaded onto your local PC. right-click --> Edit
2. Go to "Local Resources" tab --> "Local devices and resources" --> "More" button
3. Expand the "Drives" and check the disks you want to share when you TS to the remote box.
4. after connect, you will see the new drives in My Computer already mounted for you.

If you want to keep things organized and get better results, create a folder named "c:\publish" (or something else), and then run "SUBST s: c:\publish" in dos prompt. Now you will have a s letter that points to your folder. This way you can map only the folder with files to transfer to the server (the s) with no need to sync the entire c driver.

For me, copy speed is 200-300kB/Second.
Enjoy!

Answer (score 9):

If you are using mac and using Microsoft Remote Desktop app then edit your rdp connection setting, go to Redirection tab, enable folder redirection, and add the folder on your mac. You should see it in the windows ec2 file explorer under "This PC".

Answer (score 7):

Installing Dropbox on both your client machine and on your EC2 instance is one of the easiest ways to do it.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using a Mac, you must have installed Microsoft Remote Desktop ('MRD') to connect to your remote desktop (server). Once connected, edit the desktop (within 'MRD') to make desired local folders available on server as shown below:

[image]

Comment: After following these instructions (thank you), I also had to disconnect/reconnect from my Mac to the MRD in order to see the newly connected folder(s) in the remote session. But even easier is to just copy the file from my Mac and paste it into the MRD session Desktop - super easy, but may not be as reliable for bigger files. Doing it this way seemed to work better.

Comment: Worked for me. Many thanks for pictorial explanation

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to create a share on the EC2 and then use Explorer, XCOPY or just about anything else to copy the files.  Don't forget to open ports UDP 137 and TCP 445.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Got it.

How to gain access to local files in a remote desktop session to a Windows XP-based or to a Windows Server 2003-based host computer http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313292.

Should have looked around a bit before asking.

Answer (score 0):

you can use File Zilla Applciation to copy the data from your Physical Machine to the particular AWS Instance .

Comment: Can you add more to your answer? If you are going to suggest FileZilla, you should probably mention protocol and possibly steps.

Comment: @CoryKnutson Sure i will guide you .Just drop me an email . i will share my screen asifdrz@gmail.com

Comment: I know how to use FileZilla. My comment was just relating to writing good answers.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed [firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) and uploaded the file on a web-based peer-to-peer file transfer: https://www.reep.io/ , then I copied the link to my local browser and downloaded the file.